# Calix 716ge-i r2 connectivity issue

Tags: ont

I have Century Link gigabit internet via a Calix ONT and then using my own PFsense box as a router. This works fine 99% of the time, but it seems that booting up any one of my Windows PCs for the first time in the day causes the ONT to drop or greatly delay packets out to the internet until I power cycle it, then everything is fine until the next morning. Can anyone recommend a place to start trouble shooting this issue? Does the Calix 716ge-i r2 allow management or monitoring via one of its Ethernet ports? I have not been able to find docs about config of 716ge-i r2 and Century Link customer service has been less then worthless.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but maybe this will help. Someone?

I have a Calix 716GE-I too provided by my ISP. They can be logged into via local console. I will tell you what I know, but first let me say I dont remember it all because I used to drink.... alot. Not quite leaving Las Vegas, but not too far off. So the details are fuzzy, but here is what I know:

There is an access page that can be logged into. I remember your PC needs to be plugged directly into port 1. no routers or any devices in between. Hard to recall, but I think I had to go into the protocol stack for the network connection and set a static IP on the IPv4 with a different subnet or some such. It was funky in that it wasnt something you would never do, just not ever have to do that to login to a device.

I remember the password seemed generated. Meaningless letters and numbers of alternating case. in any case I recall the interface wasnt user friendly. I did what I needed via the instruction given to me and logged out. I scribbled the info down, but probably dont have it anymore. Its been 2 or 3 years...

Anyway, I am trying to get back in myself as I want to setup Client mode VPN in my router, but the filtering (probably NAT or firewall) is preventing that.

These people dont want you in the modem, and I can guess why. some of the stuff in there looked like physical characteristics of the fiber optics ie attenuation segment length etc. Realtime data from the light in the fiber optics. Technicians data. First, I'm guessing a person could possibly tweak the settings and obtain higher speeds than they are subscribing for. PRESUMEABLY, I dont know that to be true. Second, a person could possibly wreak havok on the local network and associated nodes by fiddling with the settings, again, PRESUMEABLY. So I CAN understand why they hide the admin login, and dont want just anyone logging in.

The software has stealth mode, so it doesnt respond to ping requests either.

I just dont like having to give an explanation to someone else every time I might want to tweak my network, and be at their mercy :(

There is another snippet I found. It is for the E7, but you can read elsewhere on the page (not posted here) it says it uses the same software as the 716GE:

/begin

During the ONT power-up boot process, the ONT enables the first Ethernet port and creates an IP host that accepts a static IP address of 192.168.100.100. The field technician connects the first Ethernet port to a PC and configures the PC Ethernet port to the static address 192.168.100.1 and the subnet mask 255. 255. 255. 0. The technician opens a web browser using the address http://192.168.100.100 and is prompted for a username and password. The technician then enters the factory default credentials ("admin", "fiber1ttx") and is presented with the Smart Activate page.

/end

didnt work for me, but its worth noting to PAY ATTENTION TO YOU SUBNET MASK. Mine is 255.255.248.0. Didnt notice it for the longest. specifying it in the protocol stack with the static IP also didnt work to find the admin login.

Dont have the credentials anyway, but I had planned on brute forcing it LOL. I will end up calling them. I hate calling them.

The thing is they will remote change the login after I'm done anyway...

The only other thing I know is that the 'I' is for indoor in 716GE-I so for research the outdoor model should be the same.

Hope this helps